# List of all users who have created .pst file for their mailbox in outlook - O365

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft

I would like to know name of all users who have created .pst file for their mailbox in outlook, We have O365 - Exchange online.

I tried using content search in MS Purview to find .pst file for all users in org but it shows lots of false positive like calendar.pst etc.

Just want to get user name and location of .pst file for all users in an organization. Is there any way to do this?

We have more than 20,000 users.

Comment: What sort of management tools do you have in your org? Particularly, tools that inspect and control the local devices? You're likely doing a local file search, and so you need to choose a tool that can search and report on local files for each client. This could be a script triggered by Group Policy on your domain, or another tool if you have one. You may also find registry entries pointing to PSTs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800571/registry-key-to-find-pst-locations

Comment: Purview assumes the PSTs are stored in Documents\Outlook and uploaded to OneDrive, which, while likely, isn't a given. But, regardless, filtering between Calendar PSTs (why should these be considered differently?) and mail PSTs is something you'll need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it's impossible to find the creators of the .pst files.